# Facebook pixel in react page

Tags: reactjs, facebook, gatsby

That is probably the easiest question for some of you, but I can't figure out how to add facebook pixel event to react page. I'm using Gatsbyjs and trying to add pageview event on /thank-you page.

```
import React from 'react';
import '../../components/genflow.sass';
import Helmet from '../../components/helmet';
import Navbar from '../../components/navbar';
import Footer from '../../components/footer';

const ThankYouPage = () => (

<div>
<Helmet/>

  <section className="hero influencer-hero page-hero gradientBg">
        <Navbar />
        <div className="hero-body page-body">
            <div className="container center">
                <article className="media">
                    <div className="media-content">
                        <div className="content">
                            <h1 className="is-size-2 has-text-white">
                                Thank you
                            </h1>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </article>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>

    <section className='section'>
      <div className='container'>
          <div className='columns'>
            <div className='column title-col is-10 is-offset-1'>
              <div className='content'>
                <div className='has-text-centered'>

                  <p>Thank you for your message. We will get back to you soon.</p>

                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
      </div>
    </section>

<Footer/>

</div>

);

export default ThankYouPage;
```

If I add the fb pixel script at the end of the page with *dangerouslySetInnerHTML* I get errors. Not sure what is the best solution here. I'm newbie in programming, so please bear with me. Thanks

Comment: Are you still using `gatsby-plugin-facebook-pixel`?

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you've got [gatsby-plugin-facebook-pixel](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gatsby-plugin-facebook-pixel) installed.
Then change the component from a functional to a class component, and add this into your componentDidMount.

```
if (typeof window !== "undefined") {
  if (window.fbq != null) { 
    window.fbq('track', 'PageView')
  }
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you for your reply! I've changed it from functional to a class component and added FB pixel event, however it is still not picking up. Is there anything else I'm missing here?

`class ThankYouPage extends Component {

    componentDidMount() {
        if (typeof window !== "undefined") {
            if (window.fbq != null) { 
              window.fbq('track', 'Lead')
            }
          }
    }

    render () {
      return (
      <p>Thank You!</p>
      )
    }
  }
  
  export default ThankYouPage`

Comment: Are you using the plugin, and are you testing it on a development or a production build?